# Unreal script config - section

Tags: ini, unrealscript

I'm modifying `utcomp 1.7a` for `UT 2004`.
Here is a problem:

There's a `config` key word in unreal script, that allow you to save/load variable in `ini` file, in section called: `[package.sectionname]`.

Problem is that my package is not same as original utcomp's.
So when I'm trying to use some ini settings, UT crating new section, called `[mypackage.---]`, but I want, it to search setting in `[originalpackage.---]`.

Is there any way to set in mutator package name?
I saw modified version of utcomp, that using standart utcomp's settings, so it's possible...but how?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your class is a child of the base class (in `originalpackage`), it should automatically load settings from `[originalpackage.---]` unless you specifically change them in your `[mypackage.---]` section.

For example, in UTGame.ini the `[Engine.GameInfo]` section holds settings for all GameInfo subclasses. Further down, `[UTGame.UTGame]` changes a few settings (like `GameDifficulty`) and adds a few new ones, but all of the other settings are automatically loaded from the base `[Engine.GameInfo]` section.

If you're trying to load properties from a non-parent class, I don't think that is possible.